# pass data from one controller action to another controller action in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to pass data from one controller action to another. 
I do not want to use

a. Session

b. TempData

**Logic**

Below code is about the `forget password`. User types his email for password reset and then gets redirected to another view where he can put the token received via email. Now I want the emailID from first view to be sent as the hidden field (OR WHATEVER) so that I can send **token** as well as **emailID**(hidden) entered for verification when second view is posted.
Ok below is what I have tried

**FirstMV.cs**

```
public class FirstMV
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**SecondMV.cs**

```
public class SecondMV
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**FirstView.cshtml**

```
@model FirstMV
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
```

**SecondView.cshtml**

```
@model SecondMV
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Token)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Token, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Token)
// HERE I WANT TO PUT ONE HIDDEN FIELD MAY BE FOR EMAIL ID
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult FirstView()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ForgotPassword(FirstMV viewModel)
{
    // Some code
    return RedirectToAction("SecondView", new SecondMV { Email = viewModel.Email });
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SecondView(SecondMV viewModel)
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SecondView(SecondMV viewModel)
{
    // Some Code
    return View();
}
```

I am getting error as the SecondView is defined twice.

**Question 1:** Is the only way for me to implement above functionality is `TempData and Session`. I am a beginner so please guide me. If best practice is the use of `Tempdata and Session` in my scenario then let me know. I will follow that.

**Question 2:** Can we take help of "passing anonymous object" to another controller action.

Comment: Never really seen use of the [HTTPGet] before. Trying using ViewBags to pass data back and forth from view to controller. For hidden info try @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.EmailId) Try return RedirectToAction("SecondView", new { EmailId = EmailId, message = "This person has no email." }); where message is the name of the viewbag

Comment: In MVC, the use of HttpGet and HttpPost will allow you to have 2 Action methods that are the same name....one for trip into the page and then one for the trip out of the page....see my example below.   It allows you to sent up exactly what the OP is asking about.    Typically, I would recommend staying away from the ViewBag unless you can otherwise help it....stick to strongly typed models if using MVC....very powerful.

Comment: Your `SecondView()` GET method needs `return View(viewModel);` and in the view `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Email)`. But the signature of the GET method needs to be `public ActionResult SecondView(string email)` and you initialize a new `SecondMV` in the method

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are having is that you have created a duplicate signature on Second action set (ForgotPasswordCode in my example).  You either need to send in a new model type into the Get for that second set or send in the FirstMV, which is what I have shown.  Try this and see if it works for you:

**CONTROLLER ACTIONS:**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ForgotPassword()
    {
        Models.FirstMV model = new Models.FirstMV();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ForgotPassword(Models.FirstMV model)
    {
        // Do forgot password stuff and redirect

        Models.SecondMV secondModel = new Models.SecondMV
        {
            Email = model.Email,

        };

        return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordCode", "Home", secondModel);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ForgotPasswordCode(Models.FirstMV model)
    {
        Models.SecondMV secondModel = new Models.SecondMV
        {
            Email = model.Email
        };

        return View(secondModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ForgotPasswordCode(Models.SecondMV model)
    {
        if (model.Token == "MyTokenValue")
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordSuccess", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordFailed", "Home");
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ForgotPasswordSuccess()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ForgotPasswordFailed()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**FORGOT PASSWORD FORM**

```
@model WebApplication11.Models.FirstMV

@using (Html.BeginForm("ForgotPassword", "Home", new { Email = Model.Email }, FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

}
```

**FORGOT PASSWORD CODE FORM**

```
@model WebApplication11.Models.SecondMV


@using (Html.BeginForm("ForgotPasswordCode", "Home", new { Email = Model.Email, Token = Model.Token }, FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Token)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Token, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Email)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Token)
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

Comment: `return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordCode", "Home", secondModel);` You are returning instance of SecondModel in the `returnredirect` in httppost method. But in the httpget for the SecondView conroller action you are storing it in parameter `Models.FirstMV model`

Comment: How can a return of type `secondModel` can be stored and accepted by `Model.FirstMV model`

Comment: That's what I meant when I said this, "You either need to send in a new model type into the Get for that second set or send in the FirstMV, which is what I have shown".   Best practice would be to create a new model to send into the HttpGet for ForgotPasswordCode, but I just reused the FirstMV since it had Email on it already and that was all I cared about for the example.  If your model names had better semantic meaning then this likely wouldn't be as confusing too.  It just happens that MVC is nicely handling the coercion for me, but I agree it seems a bit odd to be written that way. HTH...